# Increase the size of Bootstrap 2.3's Glyphicons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there an easy way of increasing the size of Glyphicons?
I found some solution like [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) but don't want to include new CSS library just to increase size 2 icons.

Comment: Just use Font Awesome, you should be able to subset it should the [icnfnt.com](http://www.icnfnt.com/) outage be temporary.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Font Awesome, I am loving this library!

Comment: http://weloveiconfonts.com/ is a nice CDN for icon fonts as well.

Comment: Just a note, Bootstrap "Glyphicons" are not "font icons" like Font Awesome.  They're just a PNG background sprite. As other answers mentioned, it will not scale up well. You can combine the Font Awesome CSS with Bootstrap via LESS.  You can also modify it to include just the icons you want, to help reduce CSS file size.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one way to increase the size of icons in Bootstrap 2.3. As I note in my comment, the results will be pretty poor because you are scaling the spritesheet image.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rKMEZ/)

```
.test {
    background-image: url("http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background-size: 2100px 800px;
}
```

Consider [Fontello](http://fontello.com/) instead. They allow you to generate a custom font based on the icons you choose.

Comment: So the solution to "I don't want to include another CSS library" is "include another CSS library"?

Comment: No. Yes, Size of Glyphicons can be increased but that will result in pretty bad icons as the Bootstrap uses this [Sprite](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/img/glyphicons-halflings.png) for generating icons.

Comment: While the OP's requirement might be silly, this answer still runs counter to it. (Also, a better option would be subsetting Font Awesome itself since it's compatible with Bootstrap, although the site that does that seems to be down.)

Comment: http://icomoon.io/ is a better.  It lets you do what Fontello does, with the added benefits of importing and modifying your own custom icons.

Comment: @Axel, fontello already supports svg imports. And it's interface allows you to see immediataly, how icon looks near text. That's convenient, when you pick icons of suitable style.

Answer (score 71):

Setting the font-size of the <span> tag worked for me

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="font-size: 20px;"></span>
```

Comment: This should be the way to do it ?

Comment: works. jade code: `span(style="font-size:24px").glyphicon.glyphicon-info-sign`

Comment: Note, OP asks about bootstrap 2.3 This solution applies to bootstrap 3+ which uses a font rather than spritesheet. Edited post to reflect that.

Comment: This applies for bootstrap 3

Comment: Awesome, easy and simple!

Answer (score 32):

As of Bootstrap 3, glyphicons have been changed into fonts rather than sprites. This gives you more flexibility. For example, you can just set the `font-size` and move on.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjust" style="font-size:48px;"></span>
```

Or you can simply write a modifier class:

```
.glyphicon-2x {
    font-size: 48px;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Just need to set the fontsize up :)
You have more than one option to do this:

**First** (set it straight to the element)

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="font-size:30px"></span>
```

**Second** (set it in a css file)

```
.glyphicon{
    font-size: 30px; 
}
```

**Third** (build modify-classes) **[i prefer this posibility]**

```
.glyphicon-2x{
    font-size: 40px; 
}
.glyphicon-3x{
    font-size: 60px; 
}
...
```

Usage:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-2x glyphicon-search"></span>
```

there are more options to get the third one more tiny. there for you should read more about
**[Less](http://lesscss.org/)**

according to your question and the comment that brandon gave me, you can use the above with a other icon contianer.

### Bootstrap 2.3

**First**

```
<i class="icon-search" style="-webkit-transform:scale(1.8);"></i>
```

**Second**

```
.icon-search{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.8);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.8);
    -o-transform:scale(1.8);
}
```

**Third**

```
.icon-x2{
    -webkit-transform:scale(2.0);
    -moz-transform:scale(2.0);
    -o-transform:scale(2.0);
}
.icon-x3{
    -webkit-transform:scale(3.0);
    -moz-transform:scale(3.0);
    -o-transform:scale(3.0);
}
//here i use the css from above (Bootstrap 3)
//actually you can name it like you want
<i class="icon-search icon-2x"></i>
```

Comment: This is for Bootstrap 3 only, note that the original question asks about version 2.3.

Comment: @BrianJordan actually its the same... the only difference is the icon container... but for you ill update my post so there will be no confusion

Comment: Increasing `font-size` with bootstrap 2.3 doesn't appear to change the icon size http://jsfiddle.net/Lk5vd/

Comment: oh, you are right :D sorry... may he use scale but this kind of make a nasty result :D

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
.icon-whatever {
    zoom: 2;
    -moz-transform: scale(2);  /* Firefox */
}
```

But, it will look fuzzier the larger you go, as it is scaling the image up.  A font-icon library will scale a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

You can override bootstrap's class, for example:

```
// Size and position are not working.
.icon-glass {
  background-size: 800px;
  backgroung-position: 10px 50px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

The problem is that icons will look ugly due to the resolution.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you use the glyphicons for buttons it's pretty simple:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</button>
```

The btn-lg defines the size. You can use btn-lg, bnt-sm, btn-sx

Edit:
If you don't use buttons or lg is not large enough, you can add an own class and use font-size (only tested in bootstrap 3.0). In bootstrap 3.0 glyphicons exist as .svg so they won't look ugly

Example:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myGlyphicon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.myGlyphicon {font-size: 120%;}
```

or

```
.myGlyphicon {font-size: 70px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**IcoMoon.io**](http://icomoon.io/)
a very easy to use tool for generating icon font of different colours ,size's and even you can generate sprites from you selection.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bootstrap 3, why don't you use `em` widths on the icon? If the icons are embedded within headings/paragraphs/bodies etc. then using a font size in `em`s will increase the size of the icons relative to the paragraph that they're in.

For example, if you have:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjust"></span>
```

In the css that customizes your bootstrap, simply add:

```
.glyphicon {font-size: 1.25 em;}
```

This will scale the glyphs.

Comment: The question is (probably) about Bootstrap 2.3, which still uses sprites instead of fonts. The OP should've mentioned that, though.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a very easy way—using "transform". For example, place:

```
.glyphicon-chevron-right {transform:scale(2.9,2.9);}
```

in your CSS to increase it 2.9 times.

Answer (score 0):

Try including class `lead`

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home lead"></span>`

[image]

Or rap it inside a `<h4>` tag